# How to pass a list of object to childwindow

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts2

I am working on a Struts 2 application .I have a JSP page in which i am iterating the object- list in a table with least information from the object, in each row i have a checkbox, by checking the checkbox and clicking on a print button i need to print all the information of that selected rows.
 so i called a java script function with respect to the print button and  collected all the unique ids associated with the rows and set it to a hidden field, then i opened a popup child window like: window.open("/../../printInfo.jsp","Browse",...).

in the child window i got the hidden field value using opener.document.getElementById(...)
but i am not getting the object list which i need to iterate in the child window with all its information(selected rows only). is there any way to get all the object list in the popup window without calling the action in the window.open() method.

or is there any other way to accomplish the task quickly.

any help/code/suggestion/comment will appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code, or better yet, create a jsFiddle?

Comment: i am having a userList where User having information about user details, in the action i created List<User> userList = data from database, and i created getter  and setter for it. in the jsp i iterate over the userList like <s:iterate value="userList" status="row">  and the inside the iterator i put <s:propert value="name"> etc with a checkbox and in a input button i called

Comment: the javascript function and checked the selected check boxes and set it to hidden field then i opened a popup window passing a empty jsp file as above so there in the child window i am able to get the hidden field value but not the userList.

Comment: Nobody needs information, which struts tags you use. Post your **javascript** code.

Comment: @kirilloid I disagree... I may be understanding the OP in incorrectly but it seems there is a page where a list of items to print are selected then on submit a new window pops up for printing with the details for each item.  It is not clear there is an ajax requirement, if this is the case this is largely a server side issue and would be handled by those following the struts2 tag for which we will need: the jsp of the calling action, the action code responsible for preparing the print file and the jsp for that action.

Comment: On the other hand if this is strictly a client side issue the OP should remove all reference to struts2, only show the hmtl and javascript as adding struts2 related information will reduce the audience.

Answer (score 0):

the java script code: not answer just code snipt-

```
function printAll(){
    var checkBoxLength = document.getElementsByName('ids');
    var checkedIds = "";
    for(var i = 0;i<checkBoxLength.length;i++){
        if(checkBoxLength[i].checked){
            checkedIds += i+",";
        }
    }
        //all the selected checkboxe ids
    checkedIds = checkedIds.substring(0,checkedIds.length-1); 
    if(checkedIds.length <=0){
        alert("Please select atleast one row to print.");
        return false;
    }   
        //value set to hidden field so that it can access to popup window
    document.getElementById("checkedIdField").value = checkedIds; 
        //trying to assign a list to hidden field but getting error
    document.getElementById("medicationList").value = <s:property value="medicalRecordClient.patientMedicationEntries"/>;
    childWindow = window.open("/cascade/pages/jsp/medicalrecord/print_medication_detail.jsp","Browse","left=200,top=200,width=700,height=530,toolbar=0,resizable=0");

}
```